# Issue with transpiling javascript code with babel

Tags: testing, jestjs, babeljs

ALl tests are failing due to an issue with babel not transpiling code appropriately.

Below is the error from the console.

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token
  This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.
  By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".
  Here's what you can do:
   • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
   • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
   • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.
  You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html
  Details:
    13 |
    14 | 
  > 15 | import type { CreateUserInput, CreateSlackTeamInput } from "graphql-types";
```

And below is my Babel config.

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue locally and get past it by adding `babel-preset-flow` to the devDependencies and adding the preset to the `.babelrc`. The reason it was failing is because the `import type` syntax in not covered by the `es2015` babel preset.

The updated `.babelrc` file will look like this:

`{
  "presets": [
    "es2015", "flow"
  ]
}`